# How to install an npm package from GitHub directly

Tags: github, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Trying to install modules from GitHub results in this error:

> ENOENT error on package.json.

Easily reproduced using express:

`npm install https://github.com/visionmedia/express` throws error.

`npm install express`  works.

Why can't I install from GitHub?

Here is the console output:

```
npm http GET https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git
npm http 200 https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git
npm ERR! not a package /home/guym/tmp/npm-32312/1373176518024-0.6586997057311237/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/guym/tmp/npm-32312/1373176518024-0.6586997057311237/package/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git"
npm ERR! cwd /home/guym/dev_env/projects_GIT/proj/somename
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.25
npm ERR! path /home/guym/tmp/npm-32312/1373176518024-0.6586997057311237/package/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/guym/dev_env/projects_GIT/proj/somename/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Can anyone give the package.json devDependencies format?

Comment: @Adam you can add `"express": "github:visionmedia/express"` to the `"dependencies"` section of `package.json file`, then run: `npm install` (as mentioned below)

Comment: @danny, that doesn't work for me. i wonder if there was a dist folder in that express repo to enable it.

Answer (score 1557, accepted):

Because `https://github.com/visionmedia/express` is the URL of a web page and not an npm module. Use this flavor:     `git+{url}.git`

```
git+https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git
```

or this flavor if you need SSH:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/visionmedia/express.git
```

or if you need to install a GitHub Enterprise repository:

```
git+https://<github enterprise url>/<org>/<repo>.git#<branch>
```

Comment: You can also use `git+https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git` to use https rather than ssh.

Comment: Note that repository you want to install must be a **npm module**, it must contain a `package.json` file or else you will get this error: `Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp.tgz-unpack/package.json'`.

Comment: what if I want a specific branch

Comment: Only solution I think of for now is to specify a commit with .../express.git#commit

Comment: Worth saying that you might need to escape the `#` to use a specific branch from the shell, i.e.: `npm install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git\#branch`

Comment: otherwise it uses master?

Comment: I can't install anything whatsoever from publics repos using the URL structure. I've tried all the formats above. Any ideas? **Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

Comment: @SuperUberDuper troubleshoot your github ssh details according to their docs which include commands you can run to get more clues as to the problem: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Comment: @SuperUberDuper You apparently can't clone other people's repos using ssh unless your public key is added to the project. Use https instead.

Comment: How do you require such a module after installing it... the module ends up in a heirarchy like this `@githubname/reponame`... and I've tried all sort of combinations which gives me `Error: Can't find module`

Comment: You require it just by its base name the same as if it were from npm: `const reponame = require('reponame')`. On disk the module does NOT end up in a directory matching the github username, they all just go in a flat list directly in `node_modules`.

Comment: Note: unlike the normal github clone-url (suggested in the browser ui), you do need the `git@` also for the https variant... thus → `npm install --save git+https://git@github.com:jakwuh/di-loader.git`

Comment: @OhenepeePeps it may be that your npm package requires a build step (i.e. `npm run build`) in order to generate binaries/package files (or if not a build file that generates binaries, some other post-installation step to build artefacts not in the git source repository) it is likely that the requiring module cannot find those artefacts that are not installed/created from the original `npm install`.

Comment: sadly this does not work with 'npm config proxy' configuration. So behind a proxy you are not able to install from github

Comment: I've used this with self-hosted Gitea as well. For me it only worked using the `git+ssh:` scheme and a tagged release slug following `.git#`. Repo must also have a package manifest.

Comment: How do you specify a specific version?

Comment: How do you do such a build step @lol?

Answer (score 846):

To install from GitHub, you can also do

```
npm install visionmedia/express
```

Or

```
npm install visionmedia/express#branch
```

There is also support for installing directly from a Gist, Bitbucket, GitLab, and a number of other specialized formats. Look at the [`npm install` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for them all.

Comment: What, without specifying URL? How does npm know which flavor hosting service you're using?

Comment: @Jake Rayson: it's possible since [version 1.1.65](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#github-urls) and works for `github.com` only.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows - it just tried to install from a subfolder of my current directory.

Comment: Note this doesn't work on global installs (i.e. npm i repo/pkg -g) as of npm 1.4.28

Comment: @user3751385 Global installs seem to be working in npm 3.3.8.

Comment: Note that you need a package.json file in there.

Comment: this shorthand syntax appears to use https. is that intended?

Comment: @JakeRayson it works because npm converts it to `github:user/project#branch`, I added the --save option and that's what it produced. It defaults to github appently.

Comment: @user3751385 This now seems to work for global installs. At least did for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - npm just hands. I'm on Windows with npm version 6.10.2

Comment: Note that these packages will never be updated automatically. Though it is possible to use a semver version number instead of the branch name if there's a matching release in the repo, wildcards like ^ won't work.

Comment: How do you update a package that's been installed this way?

Comment: Is there a way to do this so I can edit the node package source code, commit and push my edits and still have node automatically build the library as part of the parent project?

Comment: I attempted this and was prompted to sign in...

Answer (score 222):

If Git is not installed, we can try:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/Amitesh/gulp-rev-all/tarball/master
```

Comment: You can also use tag names in place of `master`. Probably safer to do it that way.

Comment: Yes. It will be more safer. Thank you to bring this in focus.

Comment: Nice for when you are working with branches, you should modify your answer to include a general format answer, i didn't notice the `/tarball/` at first

Comment: This is the only answer which worked for me when installing a dependency from within a Docker container.

Comment: This is also perfect for not requiring the entire repo to be downloaded. Thanks!

Comment: This is a method which instead of installing compiled artifacts, installs the source code for the repo. Depends on what you need, but this was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 85):

As of September 2016, installing from vanilla HTTPS GitHub URLs now works:

```
npm install https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index.git
```

You can't do this for all modules because you are reading from a source control system, which may well contain invalid/uncompiled/buggy code. So to be clear (although it should go without saying): **given that the code in the repository is in an npm-usable state**, you can now quite happily install directly from GitHub.

In October 2019, we are now living through "peak [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript)/[React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework))/[Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler))", and therefore JavaScript compilation has become quite common. If you need to take compilation into account, look into `prepare`. That said, **NPM modules do not *need* to be compiled**, and it is wise to assume that compilation is not the default, especially for older node modules (and possibly also for very new, bleeding-edge "ESNext"-y ones).

Comment: @DanDascalescu could you be more specific? The relevance of that link is unclear in this context.

Comment: You can't install any npm package you want from its GitHub source, unless the repo includes a `dist` folder, and most don't. The issue I linked to is an npm bug - the `prebuild` step is not run when installing from GitHub. As an example, try installing [node-influx/node-influx](https://github.com/node-influx/node-influx/issues/224).

Comment: Repos without `dist` folders CAN be installed from GitHub, for example: `npm install https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index-adder` works perfectly.

Comment: Right, because you have the directly usabel source in `/lib` (as if you had a dist folder). My point is that just including the GitHub URL of a repo in package.jons isn't guaranteed to work for installing that repo. Modules written in TypeScript, for example, need push their transpiled code into the repo. They typically don't do this, but rather use a prepublish script to dump the .JS code into a dist folder, which gets uploaded to npmjs.com.

Comment: All npm modules should have an entry-point that is a javascript file defined by `main` in package.json. So yes, if that is not set up correctly, then the module wont work as intended, but that is a separate issue, and I think we are getting into the weeds here. Or am I totally missing something?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but the trick is actually npm does not have a 1-to-1 mapping to Git repositories. Some projects build their source files before publishing rather than before committing, meaning they are NOT in the Git repo, but would be in the npm package - projects doing this will not work right from Git. Another example of how this can fail is macro repositories - Babel's GitHub project, for example, includes hundreds of individual npm packages in subfolders. They can be published individually because npm does not map directly to Git. npm publishes whatever is in your directory.

Comment: Yes, of course: when installing directly from GitHub, the cloned module has to be in a useable state.

Comment: Note that in NPM 5 this "little bit broken": it fixes your GitHub package commit hash, so now there are no difference between using a package published on NPM vs GitHub. We were using GitHub packages for *development* but @rebecca-turner seems to break that now :-(

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this later... As of npm5, npm will run any `prepare` script for bare "installs", which includes git deps. Which means the above comments around compilation and dist folders is out of date. Any package that properly sets their compilation to run on `prepare` will work just fine as a git dep without committing any compiled assets into git.

Comment: Thats a good point @jasonkarns but it bears repeating that a node module doesn't have to be compiled- it can be plain old vanilla boring js, and structured in anyway the author sees fit SO LONG AS THE ENTRY POINT IS CORRECTLY DEFINED IN `main`.

Comment: @Fergie A huge number of npm packages rely on a build step to produce code that is usable by a consuming app/library, so yes, the `prepare` script is a very important addition that allows equivalent behavior to the `prepublish` script for installs via git (as mentioned in my answer from July 2017).

Comment: @nextgentech Yes `prepare` is very nice. Compile modules that need to be compiled. Don't compile modules that don't need to be compiled. Avoid assumptions about the need for compilation.

Comment: @DanDascalescu `prepare` is the correct way. If the repo is setup correctly it will generate missing `dist/` files. Just watch out when using `.gitignore` as it can *seem* broken. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287776/automatically-build-npm-module-on-install-from-github/57503862#57503862

Answer (score 82):

The methods are covered pretty well now in [npm's install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) as well as the numerous other answers here.

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:<githubname>/<githubrepo.git[#<commit-ish>]
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:<githubname>/<githubrepo.git>[#semver:^x.x]
npm install git+https://git@github.com/<githubname>/<githubrepo.git>
npm install git://github.com/<githubname>/<githubrepo.git>
npm install github:<githubname>/<githubrepo>[#<commit-ish>]
```

**However, something notable that has changed recently is npm adding the `prepare` script to replace the `prepublish` script.**  This fixes a long-standing problem where modules installed via Git did not run the `prepublish` script and thus did not complete the build steps that occur when a module is published to the npm registry. See *[Run prepublish for Git URL packages #3055](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055)*.

Of course, the module authors will need to update their *package.json* file to use the new `prepare` directive for this to start working.

Comment: Watch out for issues with `.gitignore` files! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287776/automatically-build-npm-module-on-install-from-github/57503862#57503862

Comment: Note that the `git://` protocol is no longer supported (it was when this answer was written)

Comment: This answer is excessive here and duplicates the previous answers.

Comment: @SergeyNevmerzhitsky I wrote this answer 6 years ago and was the first to mention npm's prepare script addition in the context of installing directly from a github repo.  Not sure what's excessive about including the basic install commands, links to various documentation, and very specific info about the prepare directive.

Answer (score 61):

There's also `npm install https://github.com/{USER}/{REPO}/tarball/{BRANCH}` to use a different branch.

Comment: I ran into this issue...https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2738

I was able to change the registry to the github tarball registry and it worked.. Thanks!

Comment: This resolved some major performance issues for me. Using {USER}/{REPO}.git#{BRANCH} was very slow.

Comment: THIS ^^^^ is what I'd been looking for. My library relies on a build step and didn't have a `prepare` script. I was just trying to install a branch of the whole repo in a test repo, but since the built code wasn't checked into GitHub, all that got installed was `package.json` and the readme. This `tarball` approach using the full URL installed all the source files, which is what I needed.

Comment: @jdunning You do not need to check your compiled code into git to use the `prepare` method! You just need to watch out for issues from also including a `.gitignore`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287776/automatically-build-npm-module-on-install-from-github/57503862#57503862

Answer (score 50):

The current top [answer by Peter Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly/17509764#17509764) is not relevant with recent NPM versions. For example, using the same command that was criticized in this answer is now fine.

```
npm install https://github.com/visionmedia/express
```

If you have continued problems it might be a problem with whatever package you were using.

Comment: It also redirects to https://github.com/expressjs/express automatically now when you use this command :)

Answer (score 33):

This works for me and it is less typing.

```
npm i github:<UserName>/<RepoName>
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "name": "github:<UserName>/<RepoName>"
    }
}
```

Comment: This way is baller!

Comment: This works with yarn.

Comment: This also works with pnpm. Great.

Answer (score 29):

The general form of the syntax is

```
<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]
```

which means for your case it will be

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com/visionmedia/express.git
```

From npmjs docs:

> npm install :
>
> Installs the package from the hosted git provider, cloning it with
>   git. For a full git remote url, only that URL will be attempted.
>
> ```
> <protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish>
> ```
>
> | #semver:]  is one of git, git+ssh, git+http,
>   git+https, or git+file.
>
> If # is provided, it will be used to clone exactly that
>   commit. If the commit-ish has the format #semver:, 
>   can be any valid semver range or exact version, and npm will look for
>   any tags or refs matching that range in the remote repository, much as
>   it would for a registry dependency. If neither # or
>
> ## semver: is specified, then master is used.
>
> If the repository makes use of submodules, those submodules will be
>   cloned as well.
>
> If the package being installed contains a prepare script, its
>   dependencies and devDependencies will be installed, and the prepare
>   script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.
>
> The following git environment variables are recognized by npm and will
>   be added to the environment when running git:
>
> - GIT_ASKPASS
> - GIT_EXEC_PATH
> - GIT_PROXY_COMMAND
> - GIT_SSH
> - GIT_SSH_COMMAND
> - GIT_SSL_CAINFO GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY
>
> See the git man page for details.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
> npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm#semver:^5.0
> npm install git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
> npm install git://github.com/npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
> GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/custom_ident' npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git npm install
> ```

Answer (score 26):

You can do:

```
npm install git://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

Or in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bar": "git://github.com/foo/bar.git"
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Install it directly:

```
npm install visionmedia/express
```

Alternatively, you can add `"express": "github:visionmedia/express"` to the `"dependencies"` section of `package.json` file, then run:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes I need to install from a specific branch or commit.
To make things simple I just use https://gitpkg.vercel.app/

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You could also do

```
npm i alex-cory/fasthacks
```

or

```
npm i github:alex-cory/fasthacks
```

Basically:

```
npm i user_or_org/repo_name
```

Answer (score 11):

You can directly install a GitHub repository by the `npm install` command, like this:

```
npm install https://github.com/futurechallenger/npm_git_install.git --save
```

**NOTE:** In the repository which will be installed by npm command:

1. maybe you have to have a *dist* folder in you repository, according to [Dan Dascalescu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly#comment67527273_39490045).
2. You definitely have to have a **package.json** in your repository! Which I forget add.

Comment: You do not need a `dist` folder or any build code in your repo. You just need to use a `prepare` script in `package.json`.

Answer (score 8):

Simple:

```
npm install *GithubUrl*.git --save
```

Example:

```
npm install https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git --save
```

Answer (score 4):

**Below piece of code worked for me to install from github repository:**

```
npm install git+ssh://<your_repository_ssh_clone_link>#<branch_name_if_any>
```

**You can get ssh clone link as below:**

[image: ssh clone screenshot]

So for above screenshot repository, you may need to import as below,

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:Siddhu2/calculator-chatbot.git#master
```

where master is my branch and it is optional since I have only one branch.

Answer (score 4):

No need to do much; this helped me:

```
Yarn add <git_name>:<github_name>/<Repository_name>.git
```

Example:

```
yarn add git@github.com:myGitHub/dynamic-checkbox-input.git
```

And if you want to add some specific commit or branch name then add `#`.

Example:

```
yarn add git@github.com:myGitHub/dynamic-checkbox-input.git#master
```

Example:

```
yarn add git@github.com:myGitHub/dynamic-checkbox-input.git#c978U57
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried `npm install git+https://github.com/visionmedia/express` but that took way too long and I wasn't sure that would work.

What did work for me was - `yarn add git+https://github.com/visionmedia/express`.

Answer (score 2):

If you get something like this:

> npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/some_repo/repo.git

Make sure you update to the latest npm and that you have permissions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The only command that worked for me was `npm i MY_PACKAGE_NAME:MY_REPOSITORY#BRANCH_NAME`

Answer (score 2):

Consider one final resolution that could prove beneficial.

If you encounter difficulties, it's possible that an incorrect package URL is present in the package.json under dependencies or devDependencies.

Remove any such entries and attempt the operation again. For an improved troubleshooting experience, temporarily remove both dependencies and devDependencies and then retry:

`npm i git+https://github.com/visionmedia/express.git`

Answer (score 1):

Yarn 2 requires the package name along with the Github repository. Read the documentation of [Yarn's CLI](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/add).

Example: `yarn add <package_name>git@github.com:<owner_name>/<package_name>.git`

Answer (score 1):

Can also update your packages.json as:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "express": "github:visionmedia/express",
    ...
}
```

Then execute `npm update` or `pnpm update` if you have pnpm installed.

Answer (score -4):

Try this command:

```
 npm install github:[Organisation]/[Repository]#[master/BranchName] -g
```

This command worked for me:

```
 npm install github:BlessCSS/bless#3.x -g
```

Comment: The version is the tag / branch name or the package.json version ?

Comment: Why two commands? Should both be used (in that order). Or only one or the other? This is not clear. Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38304770/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).