# Bower behind proxy - summary

Tags: node.js, proxy, bower

I had problem with bower behind proxy, after running bower install i reveived error:

```
_http_client.js:73
    throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters.');
```

There are lots of topics, lots of solutions but no one work for me in 100% until now!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is very simple, and was in parts in many places. But let's begin!!

1. Export proxy settings to env:

   ```
   export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy_url>:<port>
   export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy_url>:<port>
   ```

   (if doesn't work use small letters: http_proxy, https_proxy)
2. Create file `~/.bowerrc` with content:

   ```
   {
       "strict-ssl": false,
       "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
       "https-proxy": ""
   }
   ```

   Last line is strange but very **important**! After I add it everything starts working!

I hope my post will help someone who spend hours searching for solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is an error with this version of bower. You can see the [github issue here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1674). The issue has been closed. This means your fix will be in the next version ( version > 1.3.12 ). If you can't wait update to the bleeding edge like so:

`npm install -g git+https://git@github.com/bower/bower.git`

If you don't like the method above [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/1767377) for a how to install github repos via npm.

Comment: I'm not a fan of installing unstable software. I recommend to downgrade to `bower@1.3.11` using `npm install -g bower@1.3.11`.

Answer (score 1):

I have my proxy configured in my environment, but @gkocjan's solution only fixed `bower search` for me.

To get `bower install` to work, I had to put it in my `.bowerrc` as well like so:

```
{
    "strict-ssl": false,
    "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
    "https-proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8118"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it sufficed to add this single line to my (already existing) .bowerrc file:

```
{
   ...
   "https-proxy": "http://localhost:5865"
}
```

The solution from [gkocjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1912753/gkocjan) did not work for me, I also had to add the *value* of my proxy (but maybe [gkocjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1912753/gkocjan) didn't have a proxy).

I've also looked at the solution of [SyntaxRules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1767377/syntaxrules), but I already used the most recent and patched version of Bower. EDIT:I use version 1.3.12 of bower and 0.12.0 of node

Comment: I have problems in 1.3.9 version. Maybe in never version they change something

Comment: If I understand correctly, the bug mentioned in bower should be fixed in version 1.3.12, which I used. But I still got the same error you  got. 
So I tried setting the proxy and that worked for me.

Maybe for you it would help using version 1.3.12 of bower.