# npm install from github pull request

Tags: github, npm

Loooking at the [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) it looks possible to npm install from a github repo.

Is it also possible to install specifically from a pull request?

Is the solution just to install based on the last commit (last sha) of the pull request?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

GitHub is maintaining a [namespace](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces) for each PR in the original repo, so this works as well:

```
npm install <user>/<repo>#pull/<id>/head
```

> NOTE: It doesn't seeem to be working with NPM v. 5. See [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181297/npm-install-from-github-pull-request/36743127#comment77828397_36743127).
> Works with npm 7.0.23 and possibly earlier versions. See [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181297/npm-install-from-github-pull-request/36743127#comment115488063_36743127).

for example:

```
npm i --save-dev json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker#pull/129/head
```

or with [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/):

```
yarn add <user>/<repo>#<id>/head
```

for example:

```
yarn add json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker#129/head
```

Note that in Yarn case there is no `pull/` segment in the package identifier.

This may be helpful if you need to automate the installation or repo / branch from where PR is originating is removed. See also [Modifying an inactive pull request locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally) at GitHub.

Comment: Yarn (or Github anymore?) doesn't seem to support pull in the tag. So for the example above it would be: json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker#129/head. There is also a 'merge' (rather than 'head') suffix for some PRs but I don't know what that means.

Comment: @DamonMaria It seems to be specific to yarn. Original `npm` client v. 4.1.2 still works with the command I've provided. I'll edit the answer for `yarn`. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Here I've specifically asked [a question about the difference between `npm` and `yarn` clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999809/why-is-the-reference-for-a-package-to-be-installed-from-a-pull-request-different)

Comment: @TadeuszŁazurski Does this still work? I have tried to install a PR for next-routes, and i noticed that it does pull the repo but doesn't seem to run it, only the src directory is in the folder tree. where as when i add the repo without the PR it has a dist directory...

Is there a step i'm missing?

https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/pull/37
yarn add fridays/next-routes#pull/37/head

Comment: @shaune Yes, it's a known limitation of npm clients. They do not compile packages installed from git repositories. Take a look at my [npm-git-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-git-install) project for more details and possible solution.

Comment: I get the message that the 'pull/242/head' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: Hello, @AlxVallejo. Indeed it's not working in NPM v. 5. Unfortunately I can't investigate it right now. What I would do is to analyze the output of `npm install --verbose <URL>` for versions `4.x.x` (where it's working) and `5.x.x`. If you are using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) it's easy to switch: `nvm install 7` for NPM 4 and `nvm install 8` for NPM 5. Good luck and please share your findings.

Comment: Worth noting that this won't build the PRed repo for you, only get you the source files, you'll still need a `npm run build` or `yarn build` in your build script.

Answer (score 30):

"[How to install NodeJS package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/6309)" mentions that you can specify a branch.

So if you know the repo and branch from which a PR comes from, you can do a:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git#branch
```

> Worth saying that you might need to escape the `#` to use a specific branch from the shell, i.e.:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git\#branch
```

> Note that repository you want to install must be a npm module, it must contain a `package.json` file or else you will get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp.tgz-unpack/package.json'.
```

Comment: If you get the following error, you might not have git installed correctly (or at all - like in an Alpine image)

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
```