# How to install package from pull request?

Tags: git, github, npm

I would like to install a package from npm `ng2-table`, but with a [pull request that is not merged to master](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/tree/785f7b4ecd1833a92bc6c94024df3f14e2b0eb6a). 
There is anyway to add this pull request on my `package.json`to install this commit instead master master on my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install from github pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181297/npm-install-from-github-pull-request)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the GitHub URL to the branch or commit that the PR was made from.  You should specify the commit hash instead of the branch so that you don't unexpectedly get other (potentially-malicious) changes published to that branch in the future.

For example:

```
"package": user/repo#commit
```

[Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: Commit is the commit hash? .__.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Yes. Usually just the first 6 characters are sufficient. Fur for completeness, it will be `"package": valor-software/ng2-table#785f7b4ecd1833a92bc6c94024df3f14e2b0eb6a`

Comment: I tried this and received this error: `npm ERR! fatal: reference is not a tree: 785f7b4ecd1833a92bc6c94024df3f14e2b0eb6a`