# How do I use someone's pull request in React Native?

Tags: git, react-native, github, pull-request

I want to use [this pull request](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask/pull/140) but don't know how to go about it at all. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install from github pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181297/npm-install-from-github-pull-request)

Comment: Or of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16350673/7509065, or of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187956/7509065

Comment: So would I use `npm i https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask/pull/140` ?