# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2'

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to install a 'Log in with LinkedIn' functionality into a React app. Therefore I've used `npx create-react-app kekap` and ran `npm install nvh95/react-linkedin-login-oauth2#pull/42/head`, considering the current version install of [react-linkedin-login-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkedin-login-oauth2) wasn't working. After adding the sample files as proposed in the GitHub readme as a means of testing the application can't seem to find the module.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2' in 'D:\workspaces\kekap\src'

My App.js:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { LinkedInPopUp } from 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch >
            <Route exact path="/linkedin" component={LinkedInPopUp} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </header>
      </div>
    );  
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "kekap",
  "homepage": "/wp-content/themes/screenr/templates/build/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-linkedin-login-oauth2": "github:nvh95/react-linkedin-login-oauth2#pull/42/head",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`npm audit` is giving me **82 moderate** severity vulnerabilities. Fixes however switch me between versions `@4.0.3` (current) and `@1.1.5` (required by outdated module I'm guessing) of `react-scripts`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? How could I troubleshoot this further? Until now I've only followed a React course on Coursera, so I have little experience beyond what a simple Google query can solve.

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine on my local machine:

1. `npx create-react-app kekap`.
2. `cd kekap`.
3. Replaced the created `App.js` with your provided `App.js`.
4. Replaced the created `package.json` with your provided `package.json`.
5. `npm install` (just that, not `npm install nvh95/react-linkedin-login-oauth2#pull/42/head`).

   - After running the above, `react-linkedin-login-oauth2` should be present under `node_modules`. If it isn't, you would probably get an error message saying that it wasn't installed ([which may happen with earlier npm versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181297/npm-install-from-github-pull-request#comment77828397_36743127)).
6. `npm start`.

Note that by "works fine" I mean that the react app is launched with no errors.

However, as opposed to the [demo app](https://stupefied-goldberg-b44ee5.netlify.app/), there's no Linkedin sign-in button.
The reason is that your provided `App.js` is different than the one in the demo `App.js` you linked to, which uses an additional component named `LinkedInPage`.

To make such a button appear, we nevertheless don't need that additional `LinkedInPage` component. All we need to do is use the provided `LinkedIn` component (which comes with the npm module), so `App.js` should become:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { LinkedIn, LinkedInPopUp } from 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch >
            <Route exact path="/linkedin" component={LinkedInPopUp} />
            <Route path="/">
                <LinkedIn clientId="81lx5we2omq9xh" />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </header>
      </div>
    );  
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I retried the steps in OfirD's solution which results in a working application, but misses the option to fill in the required clientId, resulting in an error in the LinkedInPopUp. However, as soon as I add the LinkedInPage component the application breaks on the linkedin import. As soon as I add the file locally (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory), add my own clientId from LinkedIn everything works and I get the required authorization token.

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar, you can certainly use the demo's `LinkedInPage` (which is nice, because it has an additional button implementation, but you then need (as you noticed) the `assets` folder, which was removed from that or 42), but as said, it's not a must, you can just use the provided `LinkedIn` and pass the `clientid` to it. I edited my answer to show how (you may also want to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378087/3002584)).

Comment: Also, note that the "popup" that opens when the button is clicked is actually not the `LinkedInPopUp`, but a simple window that's built with a function named `getPopupPositionProperties`. The `LinkedInPopUp` is opened once the user logs in to LinkedIn and that "popup" window is closed.

Comment: Awesome, much obliged for your help @OfirD

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar, you're welcome. Do you think it's worth the bounty?

Comment: absolutely, silly I have to do that manually after accepting your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has tried above steps.
If you still face the issue make sure you are using react 17 or above
In my case i was using react v 16, tried all these steps but wasn't able to fix the issue. But upgrading to v 17 fixed the issue..

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: It worked for me (at least for building the app with the lib, haven't tried using the lib yet).