# Send sms not working in push bullet with nodejs

Tags: node.js, pushbullet

i am trying to send sms using push bullet in nodeJs. From the push bullet docs, i got the function : "sendSMS", which can be used to send the message as SMS to a mobile phone. But, when i run the code, it is saying that "sendSMS is not a function". Can anyone please help me on this.

My nodejs code will be as follows :

```
var pusher = new PushBullet('MY-API-KEY');

var options = {
source_user_iden: 'uj*******K',           
target_device_iden: 'uj***************q', 
conversation_iden: '+91 7********6',      
message: 'Hello!' };    

pusher.sendSMS(options, function(err, response) {
console.log(response); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have figured this out by now, but it looks like the package on NPMjs.com might be a bit outdated. If you install from the GitHub repository directly the sendSMS() function is available.

Here are instructions for installing directly from GitHub.
[How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-nodejs-package-from-github-directly)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this package to send sms using node js

Install Package : `npm install springedge`

Example code to Use package ( Send SMS Push Request ):

```
var springedge = require('springedge');

var params = {
  'apikey': '', // API Key 
  'sender': 'SEDEMO', // Sender Name 
  'to': [
    '919019xxxxxxxx'  //Moblie Number 
  ],
  'message': 'test+message'
};

springedge.messages.send(params, 5000, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(response);
});
```

Its working good for me.