# How do I properly include a pull request on github into my build of React-Native-Web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, react-native, babeljs

I am trying to make use of [React-Native-Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web%20%22React-Native-Web), but the master branch version of ListView gives the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.ListView.DataSource')`

One of the [pull requests](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/pull/87) on the project adds the ListView functionality I need.

How do I add this PR to my own project?

What I have tried:

1. created [my own fork](https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web) and manually added the files then tried to use npm to load it directly as per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-nodejs-package-from-github-directly), it did not work, key core components were missing. The way one normally installs React-Native-Web is `npm install --save react@0.14 react-dom@0.14 react-native-web` and I tried `npm install https:https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web`
2. adding the files directly to my /dist folder. This did not work because I needed the babel translated versions of the files. I tried to use the [babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to translate them, but it is missing some plugins and gets hung up on certain parts of the code.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just tried `npm install --save react@0.14 react-dom@0.14 https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web` as per Molda's suggestion and got:

```
├── babel@6.5.2  extraneous
├── babel-plugin-transform-decorators@6.8.0 
├── babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy@1.3.4 
├── babel-preset-react@6.5.0 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@0.14.8
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@0.14.8
└─┬ react-native-web@0.0.25  (git+https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web.git#b448fb94cb29d08057eb72e4c13d09ad808f719a)
  ├─┬ fbjs@0.8.3 
  │ └── object-assign@4.1.0 
  └── react-textarea-autosize@4.0.3 

npm WARN react-native-web@0.0.25 requires a peer of react@^15.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-web@0.0.25 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.1.0 but none was installed.
```

EDIT 2: tried `npm install --save react@15.1.0 react-dom@15.1.0 https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web` and when i do this i get an error `npm WARN react-native@0.23.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.5 but none was installed.` which is a different version of `react-native-web`(0.23.1) than the original error (which was 0.25)...?

I then tried installing react@14.5 and it showed the original error again `npm WARN react-native-web@0.0.25 requires a peer of react@^15.1.0 but none was installed.`

Comment: Have you tried this `npm install --save react@0.14 react-dom@0.14 https:https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i got the following error: 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@0.14.8
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@0.14.8
...

npm WARN react-native-web@0.0.25 requires a peer of react@^15.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-web@0.0.25 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.1.0 but none was installed.`

Comment: Then try the versions it wants. `npm install --save react@15.1.0 react-dom@15.1.0 https:https://github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web`

Comment: tried that too see edit 2 above

Comment: I just tried this `npm install --save react@15.1.0 react-dom@15.1.0 git+https://git@github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web` and it installs without any error. Make sure you delete all the packages before you install again or try to install into new empty folder

Comment: looks like that worked thanks, add it as an answer and i will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this

```
npm install --save react@15.1.0 react-dom@15.1.0 git+https://git@github.com/mcampsall/react-native-web
```

and it installs without any error.

Make sure you delete all the packages before you install again or try to install into new empty folder