# typescript generic type and undefined

Tags: generics, typescript, immutable.js

I'm looking at facebook's immutable library and their typescript bindings.

If I have this code:

```
const list: User[] = ...;
list.map(user => ...)
```

The type of the lambda parameter `user` is correctly `User`.

However, if I import immutable's `List` and wrap my array:

```
import {Map, List} from "immutable";
List(list).map(user => ...)
```

Now, and it's baffling to me, the lambda parameter `user` is inferred to be `User | undefined`. Even changing the call to `List<User>(list)` does not help.

Looking at the .d.ts for the library, the definition is:

```
export function List<T>(array: Array<T>): List<T>;
```

So I don't understand what is going on here?

Comment: Are you using strict null check?

Comment: yes, strict null checks and also no implicit any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is written in the [What's new in TypeScript 2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-typescript-20) in the [Optional parameters and properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-optional-parameters-and-properties) part:

> Optional parameters and properties automatically have undefined added
>   to their types, even when their type annotations don't specifically
>   include undefined. For example, the following two types are identical:

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
type T1 = (x?: number) => string;              // x has type number | undefined
type T2 = (x?: number | undefined) => string;  // x has type number | undefined
```

---

#### Edit

The definition file for immutable.js changed, now if you look at the signature of [the map method](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L1964) it looks like this:

```
map<M>(
    mapper: (value: V, key: K, iter: /*this*/Iterable<K, V>) => M,
    context?: any
): /*this*/Iterable<K, M>;
```

But if you go [a commit before that](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/5eaf97f93bbb300d91d8ac77dd68355b034f4d3c/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L1964) it looks like this:

```
map<M>(
    mapper: (value?: V, key?: K, iter?: /*this*/Iterable<K, V>) => M,
    context?: any
): /*this*/Iterable<K, M>;
```

And here the `value` is optional.

If you update the definition file it will be fixed.

Comment: i don't think the first parameter of the map callback is optional. The signature is this one or similar I think => `map<M>(mapper: (value: V, key: K, iter: this) => M,context?: any): /*this*/Iterable<K, M>;
`

Comment: I really have that old definition on my disk it seems! Although I just installed it. I installed through `npm install @types/immutable --save` and got `"@types/immutable": "3.8.6"`. Is there a better way?

Comment: (I also have issues with the tsmonad type definition which seems to conflict with node over the variable 'module'. I thought installing type definitions through npm & @types was the right way now?

Comment: The file in [@types/immutable](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/immutable/index.d.ts) is the latest one (with the params as not optional), but the `immutable.js` library comes with its' own `.d.ts` file and the compiler might be using that instead of the `@types/immutable`. Check what you have there, maybe you need to update your `immutable.js` lib.

Comment: i have "immutable": "3.8.1" in my package.json, seems to be the latest :(

Comment: immutables 3.8.1 has the bug still => https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/v3.8.1/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L1965 not sure now how to tell the compiler to use the other definition or something...

Comment: OK I think I fixed it with `npm install --save https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/tarball/0155f1c7b2e9c575b2090ff0e5e9093ae1039c87` (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/32436218/516188)