# npm install fails when package is installed via github

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I install a module (`electron-window-manager`which installs `melanke-WatchJs`from its git repository) and `npm` crashes, only in my Windows 10 Laptop since in my Windows 7 PC everything is okay.

Now I noticed that every module that I try to install via git returns the same error:

```
npm ERR! git clone C:\Users\Malés\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-git-github-com-visionmedia-express-git-d7a03b88 C:\Users\MALS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-14036-6a70847d\git-cache-3d25afee\fb3946f4549395b2f0d3a166ef74eb407d11549b:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "git+https://git@github.com/visionmedia/express.git"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone C:\Users\Malés\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-git-github-com-visionmedia-express-git-d7a03b88 C:\Users\MALS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-14036-6a70847d\git-cache-3d25afee\fb3946f4549395b2f0d3a166ef74eb407d11549b
npm ERR! "git-upload-pack 'C:\Users\Malés\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git_remotes\git-https-git-github-com-visionmedia-express-git-d7a03b88'":git-upload-pack 'C:\Users\Malés\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-git-github-com-visionmedia-express-git-d7a03b88': No such file or directory
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Programming\Electron\MUVTIME_Electron\npm-debug.log
```

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-nodejs-package-from-github-directly) and did not solve my problem.

I already reinstalled Git, updated Node for the newest stable version (v6.9.5 which includes npm 3.10.10), ran the same commands in administrator mode and nothing solved it.

Please help.

Comment: Try to delete the whole cache and run npm install again.

Comment: Already tried that as well.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same issue...
Run the git bash or the command line console as an administrator when launching the npm install command
Worked for me ! ;)