# yarn: how to install scoped package from github branch

Tags: yarnpkg

I want to install `@nuxtjs/axios`, but [from my fork](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/modules/blob/axios_vue_overlap_fix/modules/axios/package.json)

> url - https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/modules
>
> branch - axios_vue_overlap_fix
>
> package name - @nuxtjs/axios

what command should I use?

Comment: Why do you have the [tag:yarn] tag? Do you want to use the yarn CLI specifically?

Comment: generally yes, I hoped that commands for them would be similar

Comment: Please make your intent clearer, otherwise it is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17509669/1233251

Comment: @E_net4 I had thought it might be a dupe, too, but I wanted to research the potential difference in installing a _scoped_ package from GitHub. Turns out there isn't really one, but you still have to jump through a few hoops for this specific project.

Comment: I had also interpreted the inclusion of both tags as "I'll accept an answer in either", so I provided only an `npm` solution. Perhaps it will be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*: This question originally had both `npm` and `yarn` tags. I'll leave this in case someone else finds it useful.

As far as I understand, `npm` maps GitHub packages to *repository roots.* Since the nuxtjs "modules" repository appears to be pile of largely-independent packages, you might have to jump through some hoops.

I got it working this way.

Install your whole fork, note the `git+https` syntax, and the branch identifier `#` following the repo URL:

```
npm install git+https://git@github.com/BjornMelgaard/modules#axios_vue_overlap_fix
```

Then `npm install` the dependencies of the `axios` module (because of the repo structure, npm will not do this for you):

```
cd node_modules/@nuxtjs/modules/modules/axios && npm install
```

And require it like so:

```
const axios = require('@nuxtjs/modules/modules/axios')
```

Comment: its sad that I cannot install scoped package without changing project code

Comment: @bjornmelgaard Do you mean that you need the extra steps? It's not _because it's scoped_ I think. It's because the module exists within a larger repo as a sub-folder rather than as its own repo. There's no requirement that scoped packages live all under the same repo, but it's probably easier for nuxt team to manage that way.

Comment: yes, but I install packages separately (only `@nuxtjs/axios` in package.json, not whole `@nuxtjs/modules`), and with your approach I have to install all   `@nuxtjs/modules` and then pick modules that I need, by changing project code

Comment: @bjornmelgaard Yes, that's because of _the structure of the nuxtjs repository_. If they had made individual repositories for each module you wouldn't need to do that. It's just how `npm` works. `yarn`, however, may be different.

Comment: why npm/yarn cant just accept path to module's package.json and figure out all other things by itself?