# Create template on npmjs

Tags: templates, npm, boilerplate

I would like to create my first npmjs boiler project.

So if I were to run: `npm install my-boilerplate dir` it should create a new project in the `dir` folder with my structure.

But after a lot of research I couldn't find any description for it and i was able only able to create an npm module (not a project boilerplate/template).

Can anyone share the steps for the solution?

Comment: You sound like you're looking for something *like* a [yeoman generator](http://yeoman.io/generators/)?

Comment: I can deal with this solution and many thanks for it.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you're looking for something like a [yeoman generator](http://yeoman.io/generators/).

Generators, generically, will do what you want: create project boilerplate without themselves being the project.

Another alternative is to make it a github project and npm install from git, (as per [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)). The advantage of this over simply *cloning* the git project is that npm will not create a `/.git` repo from the project.