# How do I fix a vulnerable npm package in my package-lock.json that isn't listed in the package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

GitHub is telling me that a dependency in my `package-lock.json` file is vulnerable and outdated. The problem is that if I do `npm install` or `npm update`, neither of them update the dependency in the `package-lock.json` file.

I've done a lot of googling on this, as well as deleted the file and done `npm install`.

The package in question is Hoek, which I don't actually have in my `package.json` file.

Comment: try deleting you package-lock.json and run npm install again

Comment: You could check your dependencies to find out which one depends on hoek and update that one. (But You could also be out of luck and that dependency has no newer version.)

Comment: I would suggest the same of @RishikeshDhokare

Comment: I did as @RishikeshDhokare said. Problem solved for myself

Comment: As Rishikesh Dhokare noted, removing my `package-lock.json` file and the reinstalling all my packages did the trick. Not sure why but, wow, what a frustrating problem.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It sounds like Hoek is a dependency of one of your dependencies (so, a package you have in your package.json is requiring it from it's own package.json).

You've already tried deleting/reinstalling and updating your project dependencies without success, so it seems that the package dependency in question has an explicit or max version specified.

Without seeing the package.json for each of your dependencies, it would be difficult to advise further on how to force an update.

**Edit:**
To help you identify which packages are using which dependencies, you can use NPM's `ls` command: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

For example, to see which packages are using Hoek:
`npm ls hoek`

**Edit 2:**
As Ulysse BN correctly points out, if you have NPM version 6 or later, you can use `npm audit fix` to ask NPM to attempt to fix the vulnerabilities for you.

**Edit 3:**
Those reading this should also check out JBallin's answer below. It expands on information I have given here, and is (in my opinion) a more structured answer that addresses OP's question better. However - if you want a quick fix - this answer should suffice.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a different package (Growl). I'm guessing it's some version of something in my `package.json` that depends on the specific (vulnerable) version of Growl. Your answer is on the right track and you could perhaps nail it if you could share the command that will show which package(s) in `package.json` that depend on the vulnerable one showing in `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Are you sure that an additional question was warranted? They seem like duplicates.

Comment: @JBallin my answer has been updated several times since. It may not have qualified as a duplicate originally.

Answer (score 50):

TLDR: Update the parent package using `npm i $PARENT_PKG_NAME`.

---

**Note**

When updating dependencies, you should review the CHANGELOG for any breaking changes.

**Diagnosis**

`npm audit` will reveal both the vulnerable package (note that you'll need a package-lock.json file for this, so you'll need to run `npm i`), as well as the package that it is a dependency of (if applicable). Note that you can also use `npm ls $CHILD_PKG_NAME` to see its parent dependencies.

**Quick Fix Attempt**

`npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` are worth a try, but sometimes the fix will need to be done manually (see below).

**Manual Fix**

Most likely the parent package will have already fixed their dependencies (you can verify this by going to their GitHub and reviewing the recent commits--or just seeing if this fixes it), so you can just run `npm i $PARENT_PKG_NAME @$NEW_VERSION` and it will update your package-lock.json.

**If parent has not fixed the vulnerability**

If the maintainer doesn't seem to be responsive, you may consider using an alternative package that accomplishes the same thing or forking the package and updating the vulnerability yourself.

**Verify Fix**

You can now verify that it worked by running `npm audit` and ensuring that no vulnerabilities are showing up. Commit your changes, push them to GitHub, refresh your notifications/alerts and they should be gone!

Comment: What about as in my case the Quick Fix does not work neither the manual in this answer as the parent is a framework that in the update changed completely API and get even rid of that library? This because the parent fraemwork still use the old library. Indeed the old is still mantenained but not updated, I mean how I could proceed?

Comment: @CarmineTambascia if the package you’re using isn’t fixing its vulnerabilities (I would open an issue/PR in hopes it would get fixed) - I would consider making your own fork of the package(s), fix the vulns, in place of the affected package.

Comment: is there a way to update child package? In case where the parent package has not been corrected for vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Harshita see section titled "If parent has not fixed the vulnerability"

Comment: @JBallin This is one of the most useful answers I've come across but the dependencies we are using are not opensource and are maintained by closed teams.

Comment: @Harshita have you reached out to them? It's in their interest to fix those vulnerabilities as well.

Answer (score 15):

**Step 1: Install Peer Dependencies**

```sh
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

**Step 2: Change package manually**

Edit `package-lock.json` manually and update the vulnerable package version to the fixed one.

```sh
npm ci
```

That will install the packages according to `package-lock.json` by ignoring `package.json` first.

**Step 3: Control it again**

Run

```sh
npm audit fix
```

to be sure if it's properly done. If it does not help so, then use other given solutions.

**More Information here:**

https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable

or here: https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

Comment: An additional solution could be: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: This is a good alternative solution. If this is done inside a package that's meant to be published, then it won't work because the package-lock.json file does not get published, but for using a package locally, this might be the best solution of `npm audit fix` is not an option.

Comment: I would always add package-lock.json in a production environment. (better safe than sorry)

Answer (score 8):

If you have npm@6 or later, you can use [`npm audit fix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit) for your security issues.

Answer (score 6):

Since NPM v8.3.0 (2021-12-09), `package.json` has a property `overrides` which might help you on fixing vulnerabilities on dependants dependencies. Without touching `package-lock.json` file.

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "foo": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Note: Do not forget to check if there are Breaking Changes on the packages you are trying to override.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

> npm i hoek

npm will install the latest version of hoek and your package.lock.json become updated.

Answer (score 1):

To check vulnerable npm packages, just use following commands:

```
npm audit
```

To fix vulnerable npm packages, just use following commands which will fix package-lock.json too:

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that it was because the server on which I was running npm had an old version of npm on it- package-lock.json is only supported by newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

did you try this: go to your project root, delete the `package-lock.json` file, `node_modules` and `.cache` folders, and then `npm install`.

Comment: This is very risky in practice. Even a patch release can hide some major bugs or breaking changes or even worse (a hacker publishing a new version of a lib on npmjs.org for example). You don't have any guarantee that updating all your dependencies will keep your project working normally.
The safe way is to update dependencies step by step, create pull requests for each with automated testing/build to ensure everything keeps working.

Answer (score -5):

After installing new dependencies run the following command to update the package-lock.json file:

```
npm update package-lock.json
```