# Find source (in package.json) of vulnerability (in package-lock.json)

Tags: github, npm, npm-install

GitHub sent me an email today warning me of a vulnerability in my `package-lock.json` file. However, as I understand it, this file is generated during `npm install` from `package.json`.

How can I find out which package (from `package.json`) is linked to the vulnerable one (in `package-lock.json`)?

Related questions:

- [How to update package-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328324/how-to-update-package-lock-json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update package-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328324/how-to-update-package-lock-json)

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506971/4722345

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I find out which package (from `package.json`) is linked to the vulnerable one (in `package-lock.json`)?

(Answering my own question): The vulnerable package was named `growl`. So, the command `npm ls growl` shows the packages that depend on it:

```
$ npm ls growl
my-project@1.0.1 C:\some_project
`-- mocha@3.5.3
  `-- growl@1.9.2
```

Then it's a question of finding a newer version of those packages (in this case mocha) that use a more modern version. At the time of this answer, the vulnerability was fixed in growl@1.10.0 (according to GitHub's vulnerability analysis). So, go through the [release notes for mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to see which version updated to growl 1.10. I spotted:

> 4.0.1 / 2017-10-05
>
> Fixes
>
> - #3051: Upgrade Growl to v1.10.3 to fix its peer dep problems (@dpogue)

Updating my `package.json` to show `"mocha": ">=4.0.1",` then re-running `npm install` followed by `npm ls growl` now shows a currently non-vulnerable version of growl:

```
my-project@1.0.1 C:\some_project
`-- mocha@5.2.0
  `-- growl@1.10.5
```