# Found 1 low severity vulnerability in 1620 scanned packages during cretating new reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, npm-audit, crlf-vulnerability

I am facing an error during creating a new Reactjs app, this error message displayed on the command line => found 1 low severity vulnerability in 1620 scanned packages

Comment: What command did you run to create the app? Is the command failing, or is it just a warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found 4 vulnerabilities on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243901/found-4-vulnerabilities-on-npm-install)

Comment: Or [How do I fix a vulnerable npm package in my package-lock.json that isn't listed in the package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50328324/215552)

Comment: Or any of the other things that come up in this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=found+severity+vulnerability+%5Bjavascript%5D

Answer (score 0):

It should be a warning. You might need to update your outdated dependencies.

try

```
npm audit fix
```

Comment: after run the command  npm audit fix  some npm warning messages are showing with  59 packages are looking for funding  run 'npm fund' for details

Comment: that command should fix your outdated packages versions on `package.json`. Regarding funds.... it's open source code so they are asking for funds, it's everything up to you, your modules work anyway. You can give money to them or skip those messages.