# react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 requires underscore@1.9.1 The earliest fixed version is 1.12.1 - Dependabot alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, github, underscore.js

Hi got dependabot alert

```
react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 requires underscore@1.9.1 The earliest fixed version is 1.12.1 - Dependabot alert
```

To fix this in package.json added `underscore: 1.12.1`, but the problem is not solved as in package.lock.json still showing

```
"react-bootstrap-table-next": {
        "version": "4.0.3",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-bootstrap-table-next/-/react-bootstrap-table-next-4.0.3.tgz",
        "integrity": "sha512-uKxC73qUdUfusRf2uzDfMiF9LvTG5vuhTZa0lbAgHWSLLLaKTsI0iHf1e4+c7gP71q8dFsp7StvkP65SxC1JRg==",
        "requires": {
            "classnames": "^2.2.5",
            "react-transition-group": "^4.2.0",
            "underscore": "1.9.1"
        }
```

How to fix this kind of dependabot alerts where we cannot update library ex `underscore` which is required by another library `react-bootstrap-table-next` and we cannot update `react-bootstrap-table-next` as `react-bootstrap-table-next` is already latest which we cannot update.

Or else shall we have to wait for next release of `react-bootstrap-table-next`

Comment: Hey @vicky-kumar Getting same issue, have you found any solution to this ?

Comment: Hi @KaleemElahi there is no fix as such only thing we can do is to wait for parent library to fix on their side and than we can update the library, for details please go through this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328324/how-do-i-fix-a-vulnerable-npm-package-in-my-package-lock-json-that-isnt-listed

Answer (score 0):

Here is generic solution [how-do-i-fix-a-vulnerable-npm-package-in-my-package-lock-json-that-isnt-listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328324/how-do-i-fix-a-vulnerable-npm-package-in-my-package-lock-json-that-isnt-listed)

In this case when dependent package needs to be updated we need to check if parent package has already fixed it and we can install new parent package.

For example in above case `underscore` is required by `react-bootstrap-table-next` so we can go ahead and check if `react-bootstrap-table-next` has already fixed the alert and update `underscore` package if they have update we can install latest `react-bootstrap-table-next` if not updated we can either wait for the next release of choose other alternative package

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue along with other projects. It appears that they have not yet decided on updating their dependencies at this time. It is known that there's a vulnerability issue with their current 1.9.1 version. We need version 12 or better. Until then we just have to hold our breaths.

Follow updates here... https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/1605

Comment: This is rather a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31180038)