# couldn't deploy the app because of vulnerabilities need manual review

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I want to deploy my app But there are 3  vulnerabilities I didn't understand how to slove them. i used `npm audit fix` also I sloved some  vulnerabilities with manual updating them.so this is th manual review someone help me :

```
  Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         browserslist

  Patched in      >=4.16.5

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > react-dev-utils > browserslist

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747


  Moderate        Regular expression denial of service

  Package         glob-parent

  Patched in      >=5.1.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 >
                  chokidar > glob-parent

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751


  Moderate        Regular expression denial of service

  Package         glob-parent

  Patched in      >=5.1.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > glob-parent

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751

found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities in 2195 scanned packages
  3 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Comment: well, as the list suggests, the vulnerabilities have been fixed in respective packages and the patches versions are mentioned? Can you try upgrading them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506971/675721) gives a good explanation.

Normally, you would try these solutions, in order:

- `npm audit fix` (it sounds like you have already done this)
- `npm audit fix --force`
- `npm i react-scripts` (the parent package of the package with the vuln)
- `npm i browserslist@4.16.5 glob-parent@5.1.2` (the vuln packages themselves)

*However,* we can see that (at the time I'm writing this) the issue is not resolved in  [react-dev-utils' `package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/package.json#L57). Additionally, the package.json uses an exact version (no caret).  **These two facts mean that none of these solutions listed above will work.**

You have two options:

- clone the [create-react-app repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), fix the versions yourself and use your cloned version instead of the real one
- wait for create-react-app to fix it, at which point one of the solutions above should work

I would strongly suggest the latter approach.