# Unable to fix package vulnerability (svg-sprite-loader)

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

***Edit 3:*** Not sure what the takeaway here is - that it's a problem with the package, or something that I'm doing when trying to fix it. Would appreciate knowing if anyone has managed to install the dependencies from my `package.json` *without* any problems

***Edit 2:*** Installing the same packages on another machine leads to only 2 vulnerabilities, but again, they appear to not be fixable. NPM only recommends manual review this time, rather than `npm audit fix --force`. `svg-sprite-loader` still seems to be the culprit though.

```
                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
                                                                                
          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss               

  Package         postcss                                                       

  Patched in      >=7.0.36                                                      

  Dependency of   svg-sprite-loader [dev]                                       

  Path            svg-sprite-loader > svg-baker > postcss                       

  More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5             


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss               

  Package         postcss                                                       

  Patched in      >=7.0.36                                                      

  Dependency of   svg-sprite-loader [dev]                                       

  Path            svg-sprite-loader > svg-baker-runtime > svg-baker > postcss

  More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5

found 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities in 459 scanned packages
  2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

***Edit:*** Am also open to ditching svg-sprite-loader entirely if someone has suggestions

Running `npm audit` finds 4 vulnerabilities and suggests forcing a breaking change to `svg-sprite-loader` (reverting it from v6 back to v2??).

That fixes one vulnerability, but the remaining 3 don't seem to be affected by running `npm audit fix` as suggested. I'm at a loss how to fix it.

```
npm: 8.10.0
Node: 16.14.0
webpack: 5.72.1
svg-sprite-loader: 6.0.11
```

The audit report before running `npm audit fix --force`:

```
postcss  <7.0.36
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install svg-sprite-loader@2.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/postcss
  svg-baker  >=1.2.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/svg-baker
    svg-baker-runtime  >=1.4.0-alpha.10475b37
    Depends on vulnerable versions of svg-baker
    node_modules/svg-baker-runtime
      svg-sprite-loader  >=2.0.4
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svg-baker
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svg-baker-runtime
      node_modules/svg-sprite-loader

4 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

The report after `npm audit fix --force`

```
postcss  <7.0.36
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/postcss
  svg-baker  >=1.2.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/svg-baker
    svg-baker-runtime  >=1.4.0-alpha.10475b37
    Depends on vulnerable versions of svg-baker
    node_modules/svg-baker-runtime

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

Running `npm audit fix` doesn't fix those vulnerabilites, and I don't really know how to deal with them. Would appreciate someone taking a look who might understand the problem better than I do

*****Edit:***

package.json before fix

```
{
  "name": "vanilla-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^6.0.11",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

package.json after fix

```
{
  "name": "vanilla-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Hi @tony - I've added it to the OP. It's just a starter file I was making, so not much to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better way to fix your vulnerabilities.

**Reason:**
There is a security vulnerability in one of your packages which is not a direct top level dependency but a nested dependency. Since, this nested dependency is vulnerable which leads to `npm audit` throwing security warning.

If we somehow find a way to update just this nested dependency to a safe version, all vulnerabilities should be resolved.

To do this, we will use a package known as `npm-force-resolutions`. This package modifies package-lock.json to force the installation of specific version of a transitive dependency (dependency of dependency).

**Steps:**

1. Install it as dev dependency
   `npm i -D npm-force-resolutions`
2. Add a field resolutions with the dependency version you want to fix to your package.json. You can find a safe version from the above advisory
    `https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5`. This link is there npm audit report.

```
"resolutions": {
    "postcss": "7.0.36"
  }
```

3. Then add npm-force-resolutions to the preinstall script. This makes it run everytime you run npm install. It patches the  nested dependency in package-lock file.
4. Now run `npm audit` to verify.

```
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Your package.json file should look like this

```
{
  "name": "vanilla-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^6.0.11",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "^0.0.10"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "postcss": "7.0.36"
  }
}
```

**WARNING: Since, nested dependencies are being forced to update to a newer version, things might break due to a breaking change in the dependency. Please verify once if everything works correctly.**

Comment: Nice - should you look to remove the resolutions later down the line? I also just took a look at the package and came across this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490778/7396516) suggesting that `npm 8` does something similar with `overrides`? Does that look right?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```js
npm ci //In your terminal
```

**Make sure you have a `package-lock` and an `up-to-date install`.**
This command is similar to `npm install`, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies. It can be significantly faster than a regular npm install by skipping certain user-oriented features. It is also more strict than a regular install, which can help catch errors or inconsistencies caused by the incrementally-installed local environments of most npm users.

### **In short, the main differences between using `npm install` and `npm ci` are:**

**• The project must have an existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.**

**• If dependencies in the `package lock` do not match those in package.json, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the `package lock`.**

**• `npm ci` can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.**

**• If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed before `npm ci` begins its install.**

**• It will never write to `package.json` or any of the `package-locks`: installs are essentially frozen.**

If the above doesn't help then also try:

```js
npm install //In your terminal
```

### **Description:**

In global mode (ie, with `-g` or `--global` appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.

By default, `npm install` will install all modules listed as dependencies in `package.json`.

With the `--production flag` (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`. To install all modules listed in both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` when `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to production, you can use `--production=false`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither have changed the vulnerabilities. I assume they shouldn't happen on another machine then? You think it's specific to this one? I might try that next

Comment: No luck on the new machine - although only 2 vulnerabilities instead of 4, it seems like the difficult ones (`svg-sprite-loader` and `postcss`) are still the problem. I've added more details to the OP if it helps!