# How to integrate react library in an existing React project

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project to which i want to integrate a library. It is basically a library based on Semantic-UI-React which includes different component like axis chart , buttons , bar chart etc. i have git repository path for that . Currently do not have git installed so i downloaded the zip file from git hub. Then i copied that downloaded folder into my react project and then in integrated console i navigated to the path of that folder and then did NPM install. Is this the right way to integrate a library. I have tried this way only. let me know if there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
npm install --save https://github.com/Amitesh/gulp-rev-all/tarball/master
```

Find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)