# Angular 2 library on a private repository

Tags: javascript, angular, git, npm, package

I have to write a library for my app, that can be imported in the other application that I will make. In there will be a lot of functionality related to the get or post with my rest api.
The first think that I have see in google is to publish my code on npm, but I cannot publish there. So I have looked at this example:

[How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)

So I have writed my package.json this way:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    ...
    "myRepo": "git+https://MyUser@git.myRepo.git",

  }
```

And it works,but when I make **npm install** it download only package.json and readme.md file and nothing else (At the moment in the repo there are a few o file and one directory with one file inside).

Can you help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

My package.json inside the repo that I want to install looks like:

```
{
  name: "myPackage",
  version: "1.0.0"
}
```

And the file in this repo:

```
directory/
    jsfile.js
package.json
readme.md
```

Comment: Do you have a package in that repo? Try this: https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr

Comment: i have edited the post adding package.json inside the repo and the files structure

Comment: I don't think that this should work, because it is not in Angular Package Format. Please read the link above.

Comment: Why don't you just put it in your .angular-cli file in the scripts area ? Importing dependencies with github is a bit too much for 1 js file, but in case you need the github way :
"dependencies": {
"GitRepo": "git+https://<token-from-github>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<GitRepo>.git"
}

Comment: Well @RolandRácz thanks I will check the links and try to build an angular package. Andrea it is not github, but a private repo, and there will be a lot of files, that one up there in an example :) I will check your way too.Thanks