# Is there a way to fork a npm library in package.json and run its build process on install?

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a npm dependency (e.g. `ngx-infinite-scroll`) that I'm currently trying to fork (for bug fixes) and include my forked version as a dependency in my application. Below an example of the include in my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "github:jcroll/ngx-infinite-scroll#bugfixes",
  },
```

In the above I've forked the repo at github and created a new branch called `bugfixes`.

My problem is that the maintainer runs a build process that creates an artifact in a `./dist` directory and then publishes this flat directory to npm using `$ npm run publish ./dist`. However, when I install my new forked repo via `$ npm i ngx-infinite-scroll` the entire repo is downloaded and *not* the `dist` dir.

Now I know this should be expected. One thing I was hoping to do was at least get the `dist` dir to be created on install by adding to the scripts of the library's `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
```

However I still do not see the `dist` directory on install. Even then I would still have to alter the package.json to point the `module` key to this new nested directory entry point.

What I would like *instead* is when I install this library from github is to have it publish its flattened `dist` directory as the top level directory of the library just like how the original library installs by the maintainer building the library and running `$ npm rub publish ./dist`. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:** I am also aware via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly) that I could build the dist and commit the code to this new branch but I'd like a more elegant way, hence the question.

Comment: Shouldn't your command be `"prepare": "cd node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll && npm i && npm run build"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you can do

**Changes to your package**

You have a event `prepare`, `postinstall` or `install` and use the below in the same

```
"postinstall": "cd node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll && npm i && npm run build"
```

Then if you really want to use dist, you could do something like below

```
"postinstall": "cd node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll && npm i && npm run build && mv dist ../ngx-infinite-scroll-dist && cd .. && rm -rf ngx-infinite-scroll && mv ngx-infinite-scroll-dist ngx-infinite-scroll && cd ngx-infinite-scroll && npm i",
```

**Build in fork**

<s>Another option is to change the fork and update the `postinstall` of the package.json to do the `npm run build` and create the `dist` folder when the forked package is installed</s>

**Edit: 20-Mar-2018**

You were right, if we use `postinstall` then it will create infinite loop. You can do that in a `prepack` event.

```
"prepack": "node build.js",
```

Below is a sample github project you can actual test

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/ngx-infinite-scroll/tree/so49242809

Test it using

```
npm add tarunlalwani/ngx-infinite-scroll#so49242809
```

And it will have the dist folder once installed

Comment: Hi Tarun, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not sure the `postinstall` script works. Firstly (as an aside) it appears the `cd node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll` is not needed. More importantly, however, it seems to create a recursive loop: the dependencies for the package install and because `npm i` was run it begins installing the packages again, and again, ad infinitum

Comment: Regarding the `cd node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll` not being needed I see now you are talking about altering the postinstall script of the parent package. I was trying to alter the postinstall script of the installable package (which is originally what I am after here). I see you attempted this under the "Build in fork" part but again, I'm not sure that works how you've designed.

Comment: Additionally Tarun I have now tried altering the `postinstall` of the parent package but the build script of the child package breaks during the installation process because (I believe) paths defined in the script are no longer valid in the because of the nested directory structure.

Comment: This appears to work Tarun. My final script (tho ugly) does actually build and flatten the dependency as requested: `"prepack": "npm i && npm run build && find * -type f -not -name 'dist' -not -name 'package.json' -not -path '*dist/*' -exec rm -rv {} + && rm -rf src example node_modules scripts tests dist/package.json && ls -l && mv -v dist/* ."` Nice work finding that hook Tarun.

Comment: You may not need the `npm i` there as I could see the `node_modules` existed when the `prepack` was executed

Answer (score 0):

There is this simpler way: [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package#benefits-of-patching-over-forking)

> patch-package lets app authors instantly make and keep fixes to npm
>   dependencies. It's a vital band-aid for those of us living on the
>   bleeding edge.
>
> Patches created by patch-package are automatically and gracefully
>   applied when you use npm(>=5) or yarn.
>
> No more waiting around for pull requests to be merged and published.
>   No more forking repos just to fix that one tiny thing preventing your
>   app from working.