# Go dep and forks of libraries

Tags: go, dependency-management

I'm trying to understand how to work with Golang and forks. The situation is the following, I'm writing a library `project` which depends on library `github.com/other/some_dependency`, which isn't mine.

Because `some_dependency` is missing some methods  that I need, I fork it to `github.com/me/some_dependency`. However, I can't just do `go get github.com/me/some_dependency`, the library references itself so it breaks.

In this [article](http://blog.campoy.cat/2014/03/github-and-go-forking-pull-requests-and.html) they give a possible solution:

```
 go get github.com/other/some_dependency
 cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/other/some_dependency
 git remote add fork git@github.com:me/some_dependency
 git rebase fork/master
```

Now, this is hacky at best. There is no way from the code of the library to know that the dependency is coming from a different repo. Anyone doing `go get` of my library wouldn't manage to make it work.

As [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) is expected to be the official dependency manager. I've found how to fix the version:

```
dep ensure -add github.com/foo/bar@v1.0.0
```

But I cannot find how to set a different remote. Is is possible to do it?
As an example, in Node.js with npm it is [dead simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly):

```
npm install git+https://git@github.com/visionmedia/express.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `help` you will see this:

```
<import path>[:alt source URL][@<constraint>]
```

So to add `github.com/foo/bar` from location `github.com/fork/bar` you have to add it like this:

```
dep ensure -add github.com/foo/bar:github.com/fork/bar
```

The source location will be added as `source` attribute in the `Gopkg.toml`.

Gopkg docs for [dependency rules constraint and override](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/Gopkg.toml.md#dependency-rules-constraint-and-override)