# How to install node-openalpr in windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, openalpr

**I am using npm i node-openalpr to install , but i am getting error like :**

> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error:
>   node-openalpr package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready: node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack package.json must declare these properties: node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack binary.host node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at validate_config
>   (C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:220:15)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate
>   (C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:279:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at handle_gyp_opts (C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\handle_gyp_opts.js:60:27) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at configure (C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\configure.js:12:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\build.js:43:13
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:85:9)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:209:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
>   10.0.17134 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Sahal
>   KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--build-from-source" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! cwd C:\Sahal KA\ANPR\node_modules\node-openalpr node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   node -v v8.11.3 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0 node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`. node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update
>   node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help: node-pre-gyp ERR! 
>   https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 7 npm ERR! node-openalpr@1.1.1 install:
>   `node-pre-gyp install --build-from-source --fallback-to-build` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 7 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the node-openalpr@1.1.1
>   install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
>   There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-22T08_18_59_445Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

The version of `node-pre-gyp` used in the `node-openalpr` module points to the `node-pre-gyp` repo, meaning that on install it will try to use the most up to date version of `node-pre-gyp` which is far newer than the version used in the `node-openalpr` module.

There is a fork of the `node-openalpr` module which specifies a commit hash for `node-pre-gyp` in the `package.json` like so: 
`"node-pre-gyp": "https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp.git#8036d17"`

this can be found here :

https://github.com/bameyrick/node-openalpr

and can be added to your project using `yarn add https://github.com/bameyrick/node-openalpr`

***How to install module directly from GitHub if you prefer using npm -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly***