# Lib forked successfully but getting error after install

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've forked react-big-calendar library successfully and install through npm in project.

package.json:

```
"react-big-calendar": "github:nikunj/react-big-calendar",
```

When I start project build, getting below error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-big-calendar'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
```

**I also observed react-big-calendar module is present in node_modules.**

It works fine, when we install directly lib.

package.json:

```
"react-big-calendar": "^0.20.2",
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/4769440

Comment: Thanks Daniel, It didn't help me becuase this issue is different.