# How to utilize npm install without direct access to the npm registry (e.g. a downloaded github repository)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

How can I utilize npm install with github packages I've downloaded via my browser?

I've followed the npm installation instructionfrom [react-bootstrap-table installation](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/getting-started.html)

```
npm install react-bootstrap-table-next --save
```

However, I get the following error

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\chris\\nodejs8\\latest\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\chris\\nodejs8\\latest\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'react-bootstrap-table-next',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose npm-session a492206c70eafebf
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://HIDDEN/react-bootstrap-table-next 139ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-bootstrap-table-next@latest 404 Not Found: react-bootstrap-table-next@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: react-bootstrap-table-next@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\chris\nodejs8\8.8.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
10 verbose cwd C:\ds\jira_hygiene
11 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
12 verbose argv "C:\\chris\\nodejs8\\latest\\node.exe" "C:\\chris\\nodejs8\\latest\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-bootstrap-table-next" "--save"
13 verbose node v8.11.1
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code E404
16 error 404 Not Found: react-bootstrap-table-next@latest
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Since npm install did not work, I manually downloaded the zipped file from the [react-bootstrap-table2 github](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2) and copied the package called react-bootstrap-table2 into my desired node_modules folders, but this did not work

My challenge is that npm install does not work for react-bootstrap-table-next due to internet restrictions. Is there a way to use npm install with [this zipped folder I downloaded](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/archive/master.zip) for [their github](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2)?

I also cannot utilize yarn

According to this stackoverflow, my problem is that my server cannot directly access the npm registry. However I can still download from github

Comment: you can use github addresses in your package.json, check out the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly