# "Announce" command giving errors in console

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to write an announce command which when used sends an announcement to the announcements channel, but only if you have a certain role, that works, but it shows an error in my console.
The error is `TypeError: client.fetchGuild is not a function`

```
if (await client.fetchGuild(message.guild.id).fetchMember(message.author.id).hasPermission("MENTION_EVERYONE") && message.content.startsWith(adminPrefix + 'announce')) {
  const trueMessage = message.content.substr(10)
  client.channels.get('545343689216491541').send('@everyone, ' + trueMessage)
}
```

How do I make it send no errors

P.s. I'm new to this, very new.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchGuild
```

is not a function. Use

```
client.guilds.get(id)
```

or

```
message.guild
```

as you already have the guild attached to the message object

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get
>
> https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds

Comment: I get the same error saying that `client.guilds.get(...)` is not a function

Comment: Is client defined?

Comment: Yes, `const client = new Discord.Client();`

Comment: Within a `client.on('message', async message => {...})`

Comment: Why are you fetching the guild instead of doing message.guild.fetchMember?

Comment: I asked a friend to help and that's what he gave me, that didn't work and he didn't know what the problem was so I came here to ask

Comment: Try doing message.guild instead of client.fetchGuild

Comment: I must go, however, if this worked please mark this answer as correct by hitting the checkmark. Otherwise, say that it didn't and I can assist more later

Comment: Now its saying `message.guild.fetchMember(...)` is not a funtion

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using? You can check by going to your package.json and searching for "discord.js":"version number". I am pretty sure that yours is outdated

Comment: I would install master by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly and https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js

Comment: I have version 11.4.2

Comment: @BigChungus What's the result of running the command `node -v` in command prompt/terminal?

Comment: You first suggest using `message.guild.fetchMember` but then suggest using master wich removes that function?

Comment: @slothiful The version is 10.15.1

Comment: You can simply use `message.member.hasPermission(...)` and avoid fetching the guild and member altogether. However this doesn't solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify if a member has a role, you'd better use this:
`if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'role name'))`
then send the message inside the if statement