# Install Expo package directly from Github

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg, monorepo

For some reason the Expo team is not updating their packages on npm and I need to install directly from their Github repo. The packages are in the `packages/package-name` folders on the main Expo repository.

I put `"expo-blur": "expo/expo packages/expo-blur"` in `package.json`, but that also just uses the npm release. I asked a similar question here: https://forums.expo.io/t/recommended-way-for-using-expo-packages-straight-from-github/22022.

What do I need to put in `package.json` so that it uses the code from here: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-blur ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)

Comment: No, that is not answering my question. The packages I need to install are not at the root of the Github repository, but in subfolders. How can I install them?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You will end up having it `undefined` in your `package.json` file like this:

[image]

The command was:

`npm install Teknasyon-Teknoloji/desk360-react-native-sdk#1.0.0 --save`

I tried:

`npx expo install Teknasyon-Teknoloji/desk360-react-native-sdk#1.0.0`

**So the correct way is:**

Switch to bare workflow if you are in managed workflow:

`npx expo prebuild`

Then follow the rest of the steps from the package docs. So I then ran:

`npm install Teknasyon-Teknoloji/desk360-react-native-sdk#1.0.0 --save`

then `cd ios`, `pod install` ...etc.