# How to Install Bulksplash using NPM on a Mac

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install an NPM package called Bulksplash. But I have no idea how to install it. I've tried using several guides on general package installations but they're bit tech savvy and I couldn't understand it.

https://github.com/MehediH/Bulksplash

If possible, can anyone please help me how to install this on my Mac? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html) command, i.e. running:

```
npm view bulksplash
```

via the macOS *"Terminal"* application reports:

> `npm ERR! 404 'bulksplash' is not in the npm registry.`

Therefore you'll need to install the package from Github directly, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly#answer-17509764).

i.e. Run the following command in your *"Terminal"* application:

```
 npm install git+https://github.com/MehediH/Bulksplash.git
```