# Install @types/... from git repo

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I can install `@types/sanctuary` with running `yarn install @types/sanctuary`.

But I want to install `@types/sanctuary` from this forked repo:
https://github.com/vicrac/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sanctuary/index.d.ts

How can I do this with `yarn` or `npm`?

Comment: I know you can do it with npm. Google. It's the same for a types package as any other if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Can you give me the command for doing this? something like `yarn install ...` or `npm install ...`?

Answer (score 3):

Yarn and npm have their own registries so that when you tell them to install (e.g.) @types/express, they will look through their files and hand them to you. GitHub repos, and any other package that's not on their registries will not be available to install using the `(yarn/npm) install @types/...` command.

**Definitely Typed** is a collection of packages, to which people contribute and then (I think) get sent to npm and the like. If you want to install your version of *sanctuary* then you should change the structure of your fork (or make a new one) to make it look like a regular package.

I will be using this [twitter.js](https://github.com/twitterjs/twitter.js) repo as an example

From npm, you can install a TypeScript package from a git repo like this: `npm install git+{url}.git` (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764))

```
npm install --save git+https://github.com/twitterjs/twitter.js.git
```

and then import it in your typescript files like this

```
import twitter from "twitter.js"
```

Comment: This is a very nice first answer.