# How do I load things from GitHub into my code?

Tags: node.js, github, discord.js

I am using  NodeJS and am making a discord bot using lots of API's (i am just playing around with them) and now I am wondering how I can import code from GitHub to my application without downloading it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean using GitHub like a CDN for code or something? I think that's not recommended. What you can do is adding the code you need from GitHub as a package, installing it with npm like:

`$> npm i git+https://git@github.com/user/project.git`

More info here: [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)