# Fork node_module react and install not working

Tags: node.js, react-native, github, npm, yarnpkg

I tried to fork this react native module to make some corrections, because the author abandoned the project and he was the only tool I found and meets my need, so reading an article I found out about the fork, I did this procedure, then I cloned and did necessary correction, only when having to add the module to my react project with the

> yarn add lucassouza16/react-native-svg-uri

I get this error:

> error Couldn't find the binary git

I'm new to this forking function, is there anything else I need to do?

My bifurcated repository:

https://github.com/lucassouza16/react-native-svg-uri

Original repository:

https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri

Comment: Could you tell me if my answer helped you and if yes could you approve my answer?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem, it is not about registering the npm, because I used the bifurcated module on another machine and installed it perfectly, it must be some yarn cache problem, however I tried to clear the cache and was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

To add it via npm or yarn you will need to add this firstly to npm registry. Here you have more information about it https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry

You can also add via github doing like this:
`yarn add git+https://github.com/lucassouza16/react-native-svg-uri.git`

You can read more about it here:
[How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)

Answer (score 0):

In the end all responses resulted in the same error, yet thanks to everyone who tried to help me, but it worked when I added the release version, this is the correct format:

yarn add lucassouza16/react-native-svg-uri#1.2 .4