# Getting errors while importing a forked repo as react.js dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, fork

I forked [TimboKZ's Chonky] and made some changes to it to suit my project. (link: https://github.com/TimboKZ/Chonky) I followed every step that [this article](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-forked-npm-dependencies) says. when I run npm i, my terminal returns some error like this:

```
PS C:\Users\lifan\Desktop\Ubiq\New folder> npm i
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\chonky\packages\chonky" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lifan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-11T23_14_30_825Z-debug.log
```

And this is how my package.json looks like:

```
"chonky": "https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky.git",
"chonky-icon-fontawesome": "https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky.git",
```

What should I do to successfully import the forked repo as a dependency? I noticed that TimboKZ has both 'Chonky' and 'Chonky-icon-fontawesome' in his 'package' folder, which are the two dependencies I want to import. Each dependency has a package.json. could it be something related to the errors I am getting?

Comment: It might just be the format of the url. Try some of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly

Comment: Why don't you want to use --save-dev? You can do with this: `-D, --save-dev`: Package will appear in your `devDependencies`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)

Comment: @huseyint Could you show me the full code?

Comment: @SimplyComplexable this only gives me following error: "npm ERR! Can't install git+https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky.git#93c076f38cf0c62797b4d5f2836ad508fb4ad219: Missing package version." And it still throws errors even if I modified the package.json.I believe it's due to one repo contains two dependencies, for which might have to separate 'chonky' from 'chonky-awesome-icon.'

Answer (score 0):

The following are helpful for your issue.

*You can use those commands in the CLI*

npm i chocky --save-dev :

```
 ...},
  "devDependencies": {
    "chonky": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

npm i chocky :

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "chonky": "^2.1.0",
    ....
```