# package.json not found during npm install --save on gitlab

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have this error when i try to do an `npm install --save` of a gitlab.com repo :

```
npm install--save git@gitlab.com:xxxxx\yyyyyy.git
npm ERR! Could not install from "gitlab.com:xxxxx\yyyyyy.git" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

I tried to clone and then to link the directory :

- `git clone`
- `npm link ../directory`

Everything works fine.

Is someone have an idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it this way: `npm install https://github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyyy.git --save`

Comment: @knud since when things aren't working? :)