# How to install @editorjs/nested-list from github?

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install, editorjs

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764) would indicate that I could run

```
npm install --save git+https://github.com/editor-js/nested-list.git
```

I can indeed run that, and it installs a directory that looks like this:

```
$ ls .../node_modules/@editorjs/nested-list/
README.md     example/      package.json  styles/
```

Then if I try to build it says:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module '.../node_modules/@editorjs/nested-list/dist/nested-list.js'.
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Note if I install it directly with

```
npm i --save @editorjs/nested-list
```

it has a `dist`:

```
$ ls .../node_modules/@editorjs/nested-list/
README.md     dist/         example/      package.json  styles/
```

It seems that what's in github doesn't have a `dist` directory built.

However, what's in github also has `dist` in the `.gitignore` (i.e. they don't want to check it into github).

So how do I properly grab and use this module from github in my npm build?

(I actually want to modify it, so this is the first step before making my own repo.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for npm 5 described [here](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2018/installing-and-building-an-npm-package-from-github/).  Add a `prepare` target that will be run when `npm` installs.  So in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
...
```