# Can't able to install ot.js library from github

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, real-time

I am learning to build a real time code editor with the help of nodejs but the issue with that is while I am trying to install ot.js library from github

[image: error on command prompt]

(Edit)
The log file's data is down below:

```html
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Archit Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'git+https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js.git'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.20.0
2 info using node@v14.17.3
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 9ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 9ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\Desktop\morningcoder\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 18ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 18ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
23 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load Completed in 25ms
26 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 114ms
29 timing idealTree Completed in 147ms
30 timing command:install Completed in 174ms
31 verbose stack Error: An unknown git error occurred
31 verbose stack     at makeError (C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\make-error.js:28:13)
31 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\spawn.js:36:26
31 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
32 verbose cwd C:\Users\Archit Singh\Desktop\morningcoder
33 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
34 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Archit Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "git+https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js.git"
35 verbose node v14.17.3
36 verbose npm  v7.20.0
37 error code ENOENT
38 error syscall spawn git
39 error path git
40 error errno -4058
41 error enoent An unknown git error occurred
42 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
43 verbose exit -4058
```

0 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'git+https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js.git'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.20.0
2 info using node@v14.17.3
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 9ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 9ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\Desktop\morningcoder.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 18ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 18ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
23 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load Completed in 25ms
26 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 114ms
29 timing idealTree Completed in 147ms
30 timing command:install Completed in 174ms
31 verbose stack Error: An unknown git error occurred
31 verbose stack     at makeError (C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\git\lib\make-error.js:28:13)
31 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\git\lib\spawn.js:36:26
31 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
32 verbose cwd C:\Users\Archit Singh\Desktop\morningcoder
33 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
34 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Archit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "git+https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js.git"
35 verbose node v14.17.3
36 verbose npm  v7.20.0
37 error code ENOENT
38 error syscall spawn git
39 error path git
40 error errno -4058
41 error enoent An unknown git error occurred
42 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
43 verbose exit -4058

Comment: You may upload the debug log as well.

Comment: `npm` and `git` are two different things. If you're trying to clone the repo you need to use `git clone https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js.git` if you need to install [the packge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ot) you need to run `npm i -S ot`

Comment: Hi Reyno, why am I not able to install a package like this "git+{url}.git"?

Comment: As per this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly). We can install like this but I am facing an issue mentioned above using this command.

Comment: Do you actually have Git installed and on your `PATH`? That's a typical error when trying to spawn a program which can't be found.

Comment: I have installed git

Comment: One more thing, do I need to install github as well?