# How to override function declared in NPM package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package

Newbie question, I'm working with a npm package and I would like to modify the original function but haven't got much luck trying. The function I'm trying to modify:

```
AnimationItem.prototype.getMarkerData = (markerName: string) => {
  let marker;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i += 1) {
    marker = this.markers[i];
    if (marker.payload && marker.payload.name === markerName) {
      return marker;
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

I want to replace this condition:

```
if (marker.payload && marker.payload.name === markerName)
```

with this:

```
if (marker.payload && marker.payload.name.cm === markerName)
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Use `patch-package`: I got some weird error similar to [this](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package/issues/337) but haven't got any fix so far.

I'm trying to override the prototype locally in my React component (until the PR to fix this issue is merge in the source code) but I'm not sure how should I go about it, any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to just do `AnimationItem.prototype.getMarkerData = <your own implementation>`

Comment: where should this code be put? I'm thinking where I import my package (which is in my React component) but the syntax seems a bit off to be put in there.

Comment: Put it anywhere that it'll run exactly once

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the package to a different directory (or git cloning it) in your computer, then make your changes inside, change it's name/version inside the `package.json` file then [link it](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) with `npm link`. After linking it, you can go back to your project and install the package with new name/version (`npm install packagename` , `npm install packagename@version`).

Or you can fork it, make your changes then install the dependency from a git URL. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/18312559) of how you can install a package from a git URL.