# In package.json, how can I specify to download a file from a direct URL?

Tags: node.js

The file happens to be on GitHub, so I know that the URL starts with `"http://raw.githubusercontent.com`.

But it is not part of an official NPM package, so I need to download it directly from that URL somehow.

I'm not sure what syntax to use, and whether to put it under `dependencies` or `devDependencies` or some other group.

I know that I have the option of implementing a script for downloading that file, and then specify the name of that script under the `scripts` group (as the `install` or `preinstall` attribute).

But I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of file? Is it code from a repository? are you using any package managers?

Comment: @OmarOmeiri: It's a JSON file inside a GitHub repository which was not published as an NPM package.

Comment: I dont think you can download a single file from github and add it as a dependency. The most you can do is adding the entire repository with `npm i github:<UserName>/<RepoName>` or `yarn install github:<UserName>/<RepoName>`. If you really want the single file, I'd use a bash script to download it and add to the `scripts` in `package.json`

Comment: @OmarOmeiri: This repo was not published as as NPM package. Is it still possible? If yes - is it possible to add a line on package.json? What line should it be? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Even if it is not published, but it still needs to be a public repo or you have to have ssh auth. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69503300/11127541).