# Node.js script returns an empty array

Tags: node.js

I'm still learning Node.js

I have been able to run some scripts successuly before.

I'm trying to use a new module I found (Github https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper)

I am running into an issue when trying to run one of the functions.

If I try one of the functions, like here:

```js
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.suggest({term: 'candy'}).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Which I save in search.js

If I then execute:

```
node search.js
```

the terminal returns:

```
[]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It is [broken for many years](https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper/issues/148). Someone apparently [contributed a fix](https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper/issues/177) half a year ago but there was [no new version released since then](https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper/blame/56f5f0f0cd31cf5e65738643a4b25a5bc7eef2ef/package.json#L3), so you'd have to [install the version from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/1871033) instead of using the version from the npm registry. If you have bugs with a library, always check the issues on GitHub first!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about bugs in a 3rd party library