# Javascript npm packages

Tags: node.js

how to import the modules or packages of a folder that I installed from github, I knew a way in the vs code terminal but I forgot

how to import the modules or packages of a folder that I installed from github, I knew a way in the vs code terminal but I forgot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a package named `mypackage`, run the following command:

```bash
npm install /path/to/mypackage
```

Or, if you are using Yarn:

```bash
yarn add /path/to/mypackage
```

Here, `/path/to/mypackage` is the path to the folder containing the package you want to install.

After installing the package, you can import the module or package in your code. You can use the require (CommonJS) or import (ES6 modules) statement. For example:

```js
// Using CommonJS
const myModule = require("mypackage");

// Using ES6 modules
import myModule from "mypackage";
```

Make sure to replace `mypackage` with the actual name of the package ^^

Comment: For installing via URL see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/14998487).