# Unchecked runtime.lastError: This request exceeds the MAX_CAPTURE_VISIBLE_TAB_CALLS_PER_SECOND quota

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-developers-console

I am getting this exception in my background.html page. I don't know what this exception says. Can anyone explain this exception and also tell me how to resolve this exception.

The exception details are:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: This request exceeds the MAX_CAPTURE_VISIBLE_TAB_CALLS_PER_SECOND quota.
Context
Unknown
Stack Trace
:0 (anonymous function)
```

Thank you.

Comment: It means you're calling chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab too frequently. Show your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might stumble across this question.

I used an [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-tab-capture-visible-tab-full). though it was designed for manifest version 2, (at the date of writing this answer) there is a [pull request](https://github.com/kyo-ago/chrome-tab-capture-visible-tab-full/pull/2) that adds functionality for manifest version 3, The pull request has a few issues of its own which I fixed in this [fork](https://github.com/richard-muvirimi/chrome-tab-capture-visible-tab-full)

You can also refer to this great [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly) on how to directly install the packages from GitHub until the pull request is merged.