# Fixed calendar height in air-datepicker

Tags: javascript

I'm using the air-datepicker plugin. When switching between months or years, the height of the drop-down block with the calendar jumps, since there is an unequal number of days in the grid of different months. If the position of the container is under the input, then this does not raise any questions, but if it is above the input, then the change in height looks very bad.

How to solve a problem?

There used to be a fixedHeight option, but it's gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There used to be a fixedHeight option, but it's gone now.

I personally am not intimately familiar with the library you’ve referenced nor its history, but it appears [a change to introduce an option of the same name](https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/commit/3ad16e085985908b0b2d3bb97cfc37b0a6b9cbcb) has been added in [`air-datepicker`’s `v3.5.0` branch](https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/tree/v3.5.0), a version which seems to not yet been released to `npm`.

If you require this functionality, you can install it directly from its GitHub branch by running:

```
npm install t1m0n/air-datepicker#v3.5.0
```

([More info on installing directly from GitHub branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918559/269970))

Be forewarned that you will probably want to update this dependency reference in your `package-lock.json` if/when this branch is released to `npm`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. That's my fault. Didn't pay attention to the version.
Thanks again for your help. I solved the problem.